# Energy of Monochromatic Beam of Light

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, poynting-vector

A monochromatic beam of light has energy

$$ E_{\text{beam}} = N \hbar \omega, $$

$ N $ being the number of photons in the beam and $ \omega $ their frequency.

Another way to evaluate this energy is through the Poynting vector. In order to do that, we assume an electric field given by

$$ \textbf{E}(t) = \textbf{E}_0 \text{cos}\left[\omega (t-t_i)\right] $$

in the dipole approximation. As a plane-wave, the magnetic field is related to the electric field by

$$ \textbf{B} = \frac{1}{c} \hat{\textbf{k}} \times \textbf{E}, $$

where $ \hat{\textbf{k}} $ is the propagation direction. Thus, the energy is

$$ E_{\text{beam}} = \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \oint_A \textbf{S} \cdot d\textbf{a} \ dt = \frac{1}{\mu_0 c} \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \oint_A \textbf{E}^2 \ \hat{\textbf{k}} \cdot d\textbf{a} \ dt = \frac{A \textbf{E}_{0}^2}{4 \mu_0 c \omega} \left[2 \omega \tau + \text{sin}(2 \omega \tau) \right], $$

with $ A $ being the area the beam goes through and $ \tau = t_f-t_i $.

Equating these expressions for $ E_{\text{beam}} $ (the first and last) and rearranging yields

$$ \frac{N}{\textbf{E}_0^2} = \frac{A}{4 \hbar \mu_0 c \omega^2} \left[2\omega \tau + \text{sin}(2\omega \tau) \right]. $$

Does this mean that $ N $ and $ \textbf{E}_0 $ depend on the elapsed time and frequency, $ N = N(\tau, \omega) $, $ \textbf{E}_0 = \textbf{E}_0 (\tau, \omega) $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused several things:

1. Photons.  beam=ℏ, N is an average number.  If you measure the number of photons within a given time interval using a photo-multiplier tube, T, then you'll find that the number of detected photons in T seconds will vary from one time interval to another.
2. Energy in a classical E-M wave.  This should be averaged over a cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see why what you said is incompatible with my question.

1. If the number varies, can't I describe it as a function of time?
2. Usually the intensity of a EM wave is over a period, but it doesn't have to be right?

Comment: I didn't say it was incompatible.   You just need to perform the correct calculations and interpret them accordingly.

Comment: But what is wrong? The fact that I didn't compute the energy along a period? I can do the time interval that I want, no? Or that I didn't average $ N $? Can't I want an exact description? At least theoretically?

Comment: One needs a self-consistent definition for energy, in this case it's averaged over a period.  Sometimes you'll see it written as <E> .  Also, it's fine to have N photons in your equation, so long as you understand that it is an average and will fluctuate.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why I shouldn't be able to do the time integral I want. I think it makes sense to be able to compute an energy dependent on time, that is not an averaged energy. But even if you're right, and the time integration has to be confined to a period, that just makes the sine go away in my last equation. But you still keep a dependence in $ \tau $ and $ \omega $, even if $ N $ is an averaged quantity, right?

Comment: If you pick arbitrary integration limits then you'll end up with arbitrary results.  the "N", number of photons, is an average number.  It's averaged over many time intervals.  So, if you want to be consistent then the integration of the Ebeam should be consistent with the interpretation of your first equation.

Comment: Are you saying that $ N $ should be averaged in the same time interval I do my integration?

Comment: Yes.  Otherwise you're comparing 2 different things. If I average the energy of a spring over time, and compare it to the instantaneous energy, then what I am comparing?

Comment: I agree that I probably shouldn't compare an averaged value with an instantaneous one, but in my question, why is $ N $ an averaged value? Can't it be the actual number of photons? I mean, the energy of one photon is $ \hbar \omega $, the energy of two photons is $ 2 \hbar \omega $, etc. Why can't the energy of $ N $ photons be $ N \hbar \omega $?

Comment: N is an average value, because when you work out the deeper analysis of photon statistics you'll find that the arrival times of photons are a Poisson distribution.  It essentially arises from the uncertainty principle.   It is possible, however, to change those statistics using "squeezed states" but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I see. So you're saying that thinking in a non-statistical $ N $ doesn't make sense, and that this statistical $ N $ isn't evaluated in an arbitrary interval of time, but over many periods, right? That means I shouldn't include the sine. Is the expression correct without the sine term?

Comment: Correct.  You can't think of N as non-statistical, it would be non-physical.  

You should average the sine.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thank you so much for your patience! :)